# left justifcation only similar to the LaTeX3 newsletter

Tags: horizontal-alignment, newspaper

How does one gets a layout similar to [the LaTeX3 newsletter](http://www.latex-project.org/ltnews)? Specifically, the text is left justified only and I cannot figure out how. I have tried `raggedright`/`raggedleft` commands without success.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: The LaTeX3 newsletter is typeset with a document class named `ltnews`. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't use a package like `ragged2e` as that wasn't available back then (I guess) but rather set things up manually as follows:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
% Why \textwidth?
\setlength{\rightskip}{0pt plus \textwidth}
\setlength{\@rightskip}{\rightskip}
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 2\textwidth}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
```

Because of `\@rightskip` this has to be inside a class file or surrounded by `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`.

The comment is rather interesting I think ... I wonder who made it :-) I think I understand Alan's choice here, but I'm not sure that the `\parfillskip` setting is correct. On the other head it served well enough for 3 dozen newletters at least and nobody ran into the (potential) issue that I think is hidden there.

Comment: Before `ragged2e` there was `raggedright` for LaTeX 2.09 `:-)`. But it's not in base or tools, so ltnews can't use it.

Comment: @MartinSchröder neither is url.sty or hyperref and perhaps others that eventually got used if available. But you are right, that was probably the original intention. ... it is all so long ago ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Applying `raggedright` seems to do the job:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedright

\begin{document}
   \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies. It is wonderful. Just as a note for the \raggedright command, as one can see in the example by Peter, when this is used, the indentation disappears and one has to define it. Thanks again,